# Why is trap in bash throwing an error when empty variable is assigned

Tags: bash, is-empty, bash-trap

I have been using the trap function for a while now, but am running into an issue I don't understand.

Here is a reprex:

```
err_report() {
    
    echo -e "ERROR LINE $1"
    exit 1;
}
trap 'err_report ${LINENO}' ERR

existing=$(echo test | grep -oP "x")
```

This will throw an error because the result of the grep is empty. When I run the code without the trap, all works fine. I tried setting `set +u` but that didn't help..

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick :) I had no idea it was the grep's fault ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `grep` fails to match anything, it'll exit with a non-zero exit status, triggering the `ERR` trap. Since you're not interested in `grep`'s exit status here, this should do the trick:

```
existing=$(echo test | grep -oP 'x' || true)
```